# React hooks useState getting diferrent value from redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have react component look like this following code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { createClient, getClients } from "../redux/actions/clients";

function UpdateClient(props) {
  let params = useParams();

  const { error, successSubmit, clients } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.clients
  );
  const [client, setClient] = useState(clients[0]);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getClients({ id: params.id }));
  }, []);

  const submitClient = () => {
    dispatch(createClient(client));
  };

  return (
   <div>{client.name}  {clients[0].name}</div>
  );
}

export default UpdateClient;
```

And the result is different `client.name` return `test1`,
while `clients[0].name` return correct data based on route parameter id (in this example parameter id value is 7) which is `test7`

I need the local state for temporary saving form data. I don't know .. why it's become different?

Can you please help me guys? Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to update local state/component state with useEffect with clients as dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing a stale state which is a copy of the `clients` state.

If you want to see an updated state you should use `useEffect` for that.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setClient(clients[0]);
}, [clients]);
```

Notice that duplicating state is [not recommended](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lessons-learned).

> There should be a single “source of truth” for any data that changes in a React application.

Comment: so, you mean I don't need dispatch statement anymore inside useEffect()?

Comment: No, I never said that, I guess you want to fetch clients on components mount, according to your `useEffect` logic

Comment: yes correct I want to fetch single client on component mount based on parameter id, so you mean I just need to add `setClient(clients[0]);` after dispatch statement? because when I try put your `setClient(clients[0]);` after dispatch statement and set second parameter of useEffect() with `[clients]`. it's calling fetch data from getClients action over and over